# Where is dataTaskWithRequest method used?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

```
public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

I know the usage method of above.

```
public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

But what is the usage of this method? I'm confused about how it is used.All examples I see are using the first method. The method returns no data, no error to handle, nor any response? Or is that you somehow envelope this as a task and later run in a queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this latter method if you've specified a delegate for a custom `NSURLSession`. The data is not returned to the closure, but rather the session calls your delegate's `didReceiveData`, which you have to implement separately.

It takes more work to implement the delegate methods, though, so you generally only do that where you absolutely have to (e.g. you want to process data as it comes in rather than waiting for all of the data to come in; you need delegate methods for custom handling of redirects and challenges; you are doing background `NSURLSession` with download or upload tasks rather than data tasks; etc.).

---

For example, to issue a simple GET request, expecting JSON response, you might define your class to conform to [`URLSessionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondelegate), [`URLSessionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate), and, optionally, [`URLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate) (called `NSURLSessionDelegate`, `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, respectively, in Objective-C and Swift 2), and then do something like the following in Swift 3:

```
var responseData: Data?

func performRequest() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://ip.jsontest.com/")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    responseData = Data()
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    responseData!.append(data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("response was not JSON dictionary")
            print("responseString: \(String(data: responseData!, encoding: .utf8))")
            return
        }

        print(jsonObject)
    } catch let parseError {
        print("JSON Error: \(parseError)")
    }
}
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
var responseData: NSMutableData?

func performRequest() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://ip.jsontest.com/")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    responseData = NSMutableData()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    task.resume()
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    responseData!.appendData(data)
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("response was not JSON dictionary")
            print("responseString: \(String(data: responseData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
            return
        }

        print(jsonObject)
    } catch let parseError {
        print("JSON Error: \(parseError)")
    }
}
```

Clearly, you wouldn't do this unless you needed some of the more complicated delegate methods, too, but I wanted to show a minimalist implementation (which helps us appreciate the completion handler rendition).

Comment: **1)** Would a live stream be a good example of "process data as it comes in" ? **2)** It would be a little bit difficult to have multiple task in a single class? I mean you would have to keep using if-statements in each delegate method. **3)** The `DidReceiveData` method is just to basically consume the task *as it comes in* and the `didCompleteWithError ` is for what to do *after* it's completed? **4)** "you want to process data as it comes in" <-- to do such would be in the `DidReceiveData` right?

Comment: 1. Yes, streaming protocols are good example, though we admittedly don't have to do that very often. 2. It's not that hard to process multiple requests in single class, but it's admittedly a lot more of a hassle than completion handler pattern. 3. Yeah, that's a common pattern, capture data in `didReceiveData` (either appending to `Data` object or stream to `OutputStream`), and initiate post processing in `didComplete`. 4. Yes.

Comment: Thanks again **5)** I'm confused about why you having a guard *and* a catch. Why do you need 2 layers of error handling?

Comment: I actually have three levels. The `guard` of the `error` object is to make sure there wasn't a fundamental networking error (e.g. no internet connection, etc.). The `guard` of the `NSJSONSerialization` is in case the web server responded with JSON that was not a dictionary (which is exceedingly unlikely and not an error we often worry about). The `catch` is in case the response was not JSON at all (e.g. the web server reported some error, like 404 - resource not found). So the first and third errors are outside of our control and should definitely be checked. The second is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

returns `data`, `response` and `error` directly in a completion handler.

---

```
public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

is used in conjunction with the  `URLSessionDataDelegate` protocol. A couple of methods are required to be implemented. During the several stages the delegate methods are called to process the data.

The protocol method provides finer control of the loading process, for example to handle credential requests and redirection control.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing it without completion handler?